# Migrating an AnyDAC app to FireDAC fails on the AutoInc fields

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have migrated an AnyDAC app to FireDAC and I can't get to work its Autoinc fields.

The `ID` field (primary key) has been defined on Postgre SQL as default to `nextval('llistapanelspuzzle_id_seq'::regclass)`, BIGSERIAL, so the server automatically sets its values.

The column was recognized by AnyDAC as an `TAutoincField` and worked correctly, but when I now open that table on FireDAC it fails saying that the field found is a `TLargeIntField`. I change the persistent field to a TLargeIntField, but now when inserting records on Delphi, I don't get the new values from the server, it leaves the dataset with a 0 value, and when I add a second record it raises a `Key Violation` (two records with a 0 value on its primary key).

Do you know how to define AutoInc fields on FireDAC - PostgreSQL, when they are being recognized as LargeInt fields ?.

Update: I have added ID to the `UpdateOptions.AutoIncFields`, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Marc.  I'm not a PostGreSQL user myself but have you checked out [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Auto-Incremental_Fields_(FireDAC)) ?

Comment: How do you insert a record? I guess you don't use an explicit `INSERT` SQL query?

Comment: Hi @MartynA. Yes, thank you, this is what I was reading when I updated the post saying that I tried adding the column to the `UpdateOptions.AutoIncFields`. I guess I missed an step, so I'll keep trying the `Manual Specifiying` section.

Comment: Hi @Olivier No, I have a TFDQuery with a SELECT * FROM MyTABLE, where I do several MyQuery.Apend and MyQuery.Post.

Comment: Try with **query fields editor** recreate persistent fields, at least autoinc field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to activate the [ExtendedMetada flag](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Extended_Metadata_(FireDAC)) on the FDConnection in order for FireDAC to recognize automatically the PostgreSQL Autoinc columns.

Now it works correctly.